# MSMPI in-place MPI_Allreduce not working with MinGW-w64 gfortran

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, mingw-w64, ms-mpi

I am trying to use the in-place `MPI_Allreduce` with the combination of MinGW-w64 gfortran (version 9.2 provided by MSYS64) and Microsoft MPI (version 10),

```
call MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, srcdst, n, MPI_REAL8, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
```

The standard `MPI_Allreduce` (with distinct source and destination) works well, as does the in-place variant when I use C instead of Fortran.

The complete test program *test_allreduce.f90* is

```
program test_allreduce

    use iso_fortran_env, only: real64
    use mpi

    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: mpiint = kind(MPI_COMM_WORLD)

    integer(mpiint) :: n = 10
    integer(mpiint) :: ierr1 = -1, ierr2 = -1, ierr3 = -1, ierr4 = -1

    real(real64) :: src(10) = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 /)
    real(real64) :: dst(10) = 0

    call MPI_Init(ierr1)
    call MPI_Allreduce(src, dst, n, MPI_REAL8, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr2)
    call MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, src, n, MPI_REAL8, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr3)
    call MPI_Finalize(ierr4)

    write (*, '(I4)') MPI_IN_PLACE
    write (*, '(4I4)') ierr1, ierr2, ierr3, ierr4
    write (*, '(10F4.0)') src
    write (*, '(10F4.0)') dst

end program
```

This is how I compile it:

```
set "PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%"

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran ^
    -fno-range-check ^
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\mpi.f90" ^
    test_allreduce.f90 ^
    -I . ^
    -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\x64" ^
    -o test_allreduce.exe ^
    C:\Windows\System32\msmpi.dll
```

And this is how I execute it (in single process only so far):

```
test_allreduce.exe
```

Currently, it prints

```
   0
0   0   0   0
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.
```

Apparently, the `src` buffer gets overwritten by garbage in the second (in-place) call to `MPI_Allreduce`.

I saw in the code of `mpi.f90` Intel-specific DLLIMPORT directives and even attempted to add analogical

```
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: MPI_IN_PLACE
```

without any effect.

Comment: Is the result any different if you use mpirun to launch the executable (as you should)?

Comment: No, neither using `mpiexec -n 1 test_allreduce.exe` nor with larger process count makes any difference.

Comment: Works for me (gfortran7.4, open-mpi 2.1.1, Linux Mint 19) and I can't see anything that is likely to cause the problem in your code - though if it were me I would avoid using mpi_real8 and instead use something like MPI_Type_create_f90_real to get the handle for the real variables, but I will be amazed if this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the trouble is that in MSMPI the variable `MPI_IN_PLACE` is contained in an internal `COMMON` block `/MPIPRIV1/` and it is a [known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=47030) in gfortran that the compiler fails to properly import `COMMON` block variables from DLLs.

Nevertheless, broken things can be fixed, and in the end all that was needed was to apply a [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123046/2249356) to gfortran code and compile it from scratch in MSYS2 (*phew...*), **and** add the directive

```
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT ::  MPI_BOTTOM, MPI_IN_PLACE
```

right after `implicit none` in the above presented code. (Both these variables seem to be needed in the directive, because `MPI_IN_PLACE` is second in the internal `COMMON` block just after `MPI_BOTTOM`.) Then the in-place `MPI_Allreduce` works flawlessly.